# How to do Pragmatically bouncing ball

Tags: java, android, android-animation

I want my ball to follow the path as shown in the image. I  tried from this code.

```java
package tedd.example.com.aprilbouncing;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.format.Time;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(new BallBounce(this));
        }
    }


    class BallBounce extends View {
        int screenW;
        int screenH;
        float X;
        int Y;
        int initialY;
        int initialX;
        int ballW;
        int ballH;
        int angle;
        float dY;
        float acc;
        Bitmap ball, bgr;
        int count;

        public BallBounce(Context context) {
            super(context);
            ball = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ball); //load a ball image
            //bgr = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.sky_bgr); //load a background
            ballW = ball.getWidth();
            ballH = ball.getHeight();
            acc = 0.2f; //acceleration
            dY = 0; //vertical speed
            initialY = 400; //Initial vertical position.
            initialX = 0;
            angle = 0; //Start value for rotation angle.
            count=0;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSizeChanged (int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
            super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
            screenW = w;
            screenH = h;
           // bgr = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bgr, w, h, true); //Resize background to fit the screen.
            //X = (int) (screenW /2) - (ballW / 2) ; //Centre ball into the centre of the screen.
            X = initialX;
            Y = initialY;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);

            //Draw background.
           // canvas.drawBitmap(bgr, 0, 0, null);

            //Compute roughly ball speed and location.
            X =(screenW /2) - (ballW / 2) ;

            if(count==1){
            X =(screenW /2) - (ballW / 2) ;
            }

            if(count>4){

            }
            if(count>=4){
                X+=1;
            }
            Y+= (int) dY; //Increase or decrease vertical position.
            if (Y > (screenH - ballH)) {
                dY=(-1)*dY; //Reverse speed when bottom hit.
                count++;
            }
            dY+= acc; //Increase or decrease speed.

            //Increase rotating angle.
            if (angle++ >360)
                angle =0;
            canvas.save();
            canvas.rotate(angle*8, X + (ballW / 2), Y + (ballH / 2));
            canvas.drawBitmap(ball, X, Y, null);
            canvas.restore();

            invalidate();
        }
    }
```

But it is not following the path as required.

I want my ball to follow the given mention image and also have to control the bouncing part,Actually wants to implement this part of animation in my app so that the ball has to bounce until the data as loaded from the server and ,after that its have to right side of the screen.

Please help me out how to do this thing.

**Ball's path :**
[image]

Comment: if you any further information from my side,let me know.